# Array length does not match index when creating a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am constructing a dataframe from:

```
datetoday = (pd.to_datetime(files[-1]['file_published'], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
datetoday
Out[66]: '2022-11-23'
dates = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 337, 1))
dates
Out[68]: 
    0        1
    1        2
    2        3
    3        4
    4        5
          ... 
    331    332
    332    333
    333    334
    334    335
    335    336
Length: 336, dtype: int64
```

And then adding a data column:

```
data = pd.read_excel(files[0]['file_path'], sheet_name='Sheet1', engine='openpyxl').iloc[1:, 3:].astype(
    float).dropna(axis=1).values.flatten()

len(data)
Out[73]: 336
```

But when I create the final dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datecreated': datetoday, 'timestamp': dates, 'ipto_weekly_forecast': data})
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: array length 0 does not match index length 336
```

The strange thing is that the error happens on Jupyter but locally on PyCharm the `df` gets built without issues.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

## Conjecture

The older version of pandas you are using on Jupyter is fussing about the way you are specifying the `datecreated` column using a **scalar** value (note for the other two columns, you specified using **lists/arrays**).

## Solution

The following fix will work on any version of pandas (given that the `dates` and `data` lists are, in fact, length 336):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'datecreated': [datetoday]*336,
    'timestamp': dates,
    'ipto_weekly_forecast': data
})
```

Here is an example using mocked data.

```
dates = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 337, 1))
data = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 337, 1))
datetoday = '2022-11-23'

df = pd.DataFrame({'datecreated': [datetoday]*336, 'timestamp': dates, 'ipto_weekly_forecast': data})
```

### Explanation

The solution works because the expression `[datetoday]*336` evaluates to a list of length 336 with every value equal to `datetoday`. Now, we are providing pandas with data of the same length for every column.

---

Note: it was my intention to provide this information in more condensed format as a comment, but I do not have enough reputation to comment.

Comment: i did add your proposed solution and now the new error is: ValueError: arrays must all be same length